# Transfer encoding chunked: Ordering and loss of chunk

Tags: http, http-headers, chunked-encoding

I had a query regarding HTTP chunked transfer encoding. Is there a possibility that the chunks would arrive in different order and how is it reordered in that case?
Similarly, if one of the chunks is lost, is there a way to detect it?

I had checked http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html, but couldn't find anything in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current spec is http://svn.tools.ietf.org/svn/wg/httpbis/specs/rfc7230.html#chunked.encoding.

And no, chunks can not arrive out-of-order, and there's no way to detect a lost chunk.